# Normal permission is part of permission group that has non normal permissions. Does this grant all the group

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

So I have been reading the permission doc on Android developer official website with regard to the new permission model. One thing that confuses me is, the permission group. They say that if your user accept a permission from this permission group then all of the permissions in that group is granted.

Now what if this permission group has a "NORMAL PERMISSION". For example, getAccounts is a normal permission which means it is granted at install time. Does that make all the permission group (which includes non normal ones such as getContacts) granted by default? According to the docs, it should! But that does not make sense since getContacts is not normal permission.

Any idea how this works in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET_ACCOUNTS` is not a normal permission any more - it is dangerous as of [Developer Preview 3](http://developer.android.com/preview/support.html#changes). You'll find that only dangerous permissions in a permission group can be granted/revoked and are granted/revoked as a group.

Comment: Oh so  https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html   is outdated then! wow that was the page linked from my dev consol  announcement page. Thanks for the answer